# Сборка многомодульного проекта [Gradle]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, build-automation

Использую IDEA. Есть проект. В нём есть три модуля:

1. ModuleV1
2. ModuleV2
3. ModuleCommon

Модули ModuleV1 и ModuleV2 - gradle модули.

Как правильно настроить сборку так, чтобы:
jar файлы ModuleV1 и ModuleV2 имели в себе ModuleCommon?

Answer (score 1):

Если отбросить не совсем понятное условие

> чтобы: jar файлы ModuleV1 и ModuleV2 имели в себе ModuleCommon

То решение примерно такое:
добавить в зависимости модулей ModuleV1 и ModuleV2 - ModuleCommon

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ModuleCommon')
}
```

Если прям нужно чтоб в jar модулей добавился код из ModuleCommon, можно попробовать собирать их плагином [ShadowJar](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).

Comment: Суть именно в том, чтобы не просто дать зависимость через Gradle, а именно при сборке ModuleV1 и ModuleV2 поместить в их jar файлы код из ModuleCommon. я позже посмотрю ShadowJar